# Blender crash on startup immediately

Tags: error

Double click on Blender. Black screen open without message. Blender window open in gray color. Both windows close.

- Laptop: Acer Nitro 5 AN515-51
- Software: Blender version 2.79a
- OS: Windows 10.0.16299
- Video: Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 / NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
- Processor: Intel Core i5 7300HG

I tried reinstalling **Blender 2.79a**, problem persists. I tried installing  an older version, **Blender 2.78c**, problem persists.

I installed **blender-2.80-cca1e1b-win64-vc14.zip** experimental build, and this build works in my computer for about 30 seconds. Blender open normally, I can click arround, but after aproximately 30 seconds, it closes without warning.

Also, I have this message when I change the sample rate of the audio in my computer:

- AL lib: UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead

but had I read in other forums and posts that this is not harmful.

Any other information, you can ask.

Comment: Can you try a [daily build](https://builder.blender.org/download/) of 2.79? Also, I've heard people having trouble with NVidia driver version 391, if you have that maybe try an older version?

Comment: I will instalI the daily/current version and let you know.

Something I forgot to mention: I had Blender before and was functional. The problem began after updating drivers in my laptop.I have the driver 391.01 installed in my Laptop this week, maybe that started the problem. If the daily build installation does not fix the problem, I will install an older version of NVidia driver and test it. I will keep you updated.

Comment: With the daily/current oficial version blender-2.79-07b07e5-win64.zip happened the same thing as iwth the version blender-2.80-cca1e1b-win64-vc14.zip. Blender open normally, I can click arround, but after aproximately 30 seconds, it closes without warning. I will install an older version of NVidia driver and keep you updated.

Comment: With oficial version **blender-2.79-07b07e5-win64.zip** installed, and NVIDEA driver **390.77-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql** installed, Blender is doing the same thing as before. Only this time is closing after 1 minute (from the time I double click to run the Blender, to the time blender closes).

Comment: It is starting to look like a hardware issue. Can you test with an Ubuntu USB stick to see how stable Blender is on Linux? Or try Memtest86 to test your RAM.

Comment: At this moment I have installed:

**blender-2.79.0-git.07b07e5-windows64**
**NVIDIA 23.21.13.9135 (391.35)**

Between the start and quiting of blender, this are the messages that appear in the Command Line Interface (CLI):

**AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender-2.79.0-git.07b07e5-windows64\2.79\python
Cycles OpenCL: driver crashed, countinuing without OpenCL.**

Blender now quits after 40 seconds.

Comment: Made a memory test with **MemTest86 V7.5 Free (64-bit)**, using all tests (from test 0, to test 13) with 20 passes. Elapsed Time: 13:12:19. # Tests Passed: 240/240 (100%). 0 Errors.

Comment: Aditional to that, sometime my computer get a **BSoD**. Using **WhoCrashed** software, it was identified that it was related to **ntoskrnl.exe**, Error: **FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE**. It also recommended a memory test, but as you can see, memory test did not have any errors. I also used the Windows **mdsched.exe** diagnostic tool to verify memory problems, but that did not give any errors either. I don't know if this problem is related or isolated to my Blender problem.

Comment: You may want to write a bug report at https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: Hi I had the exact same problem where it closes sometime after startup. I realised I was only running on Windows defender, I thought my free trial of bullguard came pre-installed (I was wrong), so I downloaded the McAfee software I had lined up and now blender works fine, so I'd check your antivirus settings, it may be that the antivirus is blocking the program.